# Bash variable substition fails. Do I need to enable a switch?

Tags: bash

The following Bash script is failing:

```
DATA=fred
echo ${DATA:1:1}
```

I expect it to print "r", but all I get is a "Bad substitution" error.

Is there some sort of switch I need to use to enable the variable expansion syntax?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you must make sure that it's being run by bash and not some other shell.

```
bash script.sh
```

...

```
#!/bin/bash
 ...
```

Comment: echo ${SHELL} prints "/bin/bash" , so I _think_ it must be the correct shell. A couple of other things. Firstly the script is being launched from another app, and secondly I've just swapped OS from RedHat (where it worked) to Ubuntu (where it's failing)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a great solution, but a workaround would be:

```
TEST=`echo "${DATA}" | sed -r 's|^.(.).*$|\1|'`
```

Thanks for the suggestion Ignacio